# share image from android mobile

Tags: java, android

I want to share png image from android phone to whatsapp but problem is that image has been sent but with black background,,  so how to make it transparent ( png image already transperant )

This is my code to share image

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.insmscollection/drawable /filename");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send image"));
```

Comment: Joining the question